# ul/li Drop Down not aligning to the left?

Tags: html, css

i'm trying to create a drop down for my settings page tab, now it works fine with no issues when opened on a desktop but when opened on a mobile/tablet or shrinking the browser size my tabs menu is all "crushed" in a sense. It looks like it's dropping down to the right when maybe if it was dropping down to the left it might fix it. No idea anyway, so I wondered if anyone knows how to fix this issue?

**CURRENT DESKTOP EXAMPLE**
[image]

**CURRENT MOBILE EXAMPLE**
[image]

**THE WAY I WANT IT TO LOOK**
[image]

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <div id="headerTitle">
            <p>Project Archive</p>
        </div>
        <div id="nav">
            <ul>
                <li class="navOn"><a class="active" href="Home.php">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="Home.php">All</a></li>
                <li><a href="Home.php">Categories</a></li>
                <li><a href="Home.php">Quote</a></li>
                <li><a href="Home.php">Support</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropbtn">Settings</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-content">
                    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div id="search">
        <p>Search Your Documents...</p>
        <form action="Home.php" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="search" class="tbSearch">
        </form>
    </div>

    <div id="documents">
        <div id="docGrid">
            <div id="docLeft">
                <div id="docName">
                    <p>Doc Name</p>
                </div>
                <div id="docDescription">
                    <p>This is the area where the description of the document will be displayed.</p>
                </div>
                <div id="docOpen">
                    <table class="btnOpen">
                        <tr>
                            <td>OPEN</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="docRight">
                <div id="docName">
                    <p>Doc Name</p>
                </div>
                <div id="docDescription">
                    <p>This is the area where the description of the document will be displayed.</p>
                </div>
                <div id="docOpen">
                    <table class="btnOpen">
                        <tr>
                            <td>OPEN</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="docGrid">
            <div id="docLeft">
                <div id="docName">
                    <p>Doc Name</p>
                </div>
                <div id="docDescription">
                    <p>This is the area where the description of the document will be displayed.</p>
                </div>
                <div id="docOpen">
                    <table class="btnOpen">
                        <tr>
                            <td>OPEN</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="docRight">
                <div id="docName">
                    <p>Doc Name</p>
                </div>
                <div id="docDescription">
                    <p>This is the area where the description of the document will be displayed.</p>
                </div>
                <div id="docOpen">
                    <table class="btnOpen">
                        <tr>
                            <td>OPEN</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="docGrid">
            <div id="docLeft">
                <div id="docName">
                    <p>Doc Name</p>
                </div>
                <div id="docDescription">
                    <p>This is the area where the description of the document will be displayed.</p>
                </div>
                <div id="docOpen">
                    <table class="btnOpen">
                        <tr>
                            <td>OPEN</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="docRight">
                <div id="docName">
                    <p>Doc Name</p>
                </div>
                <div id="docDescription">
                    <p>This is the area where the description of the document will be displayed.</p>
                </div>
                <div id="docOpen">
                    <table class="btnOpen">
                        <tr>
                            <td>OPEN</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

        <div id="docGrid">
            <div id="docLeft">
                <div id="docName">
                    <p>Doc Name</p>
                </div>
                <div id="docDescription">
                    <p>This is the area where the description of the document will be displayed.</p>
                </div>
                <div id="docOpen">
                    <table class="btnOpen">
                        <tr>
                            <td>OPEN</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="docRight">
                <div id="docName">
                    <p>Doc Name</p>
                </div>
                <div id="docDescription">
                    <p>This is the area where the description of the document will be displayed.</p>
                </div>
                <div id="docOpen">
                    <table class="btnOpen">
                        <tr>
                            <td>OPEN</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
@charset "utf-8";
body{
    background:#E8E8E8; 
    overflow-x:hidden;
}
#header{
    width:100%;
    height:80px;
    font-weight:bold;
}
#search{
    height:115px;
    background-color:#4C66A4;   
    color:#FFF;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:18px;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding-top:10px;
}
#navTop{
    height:5px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    background-color:#4C66A4;
}
#documents{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;    
}
#docGrid{
    height:225px;
    margin-left:10%;
    margin-right:10%;
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
}
#docLeft{
    float:left;
    height:222px;
    width:45%;
    background-color:#FFF;
    border-bottom:3px solid #BEBEBE;    
}
#docRight{
    float:right;
    height:222px;
    width:45%;
    background-color:#FFF;
    border-bottom:3px solid #BEBEBE;
}
#docName{
    text-align:center;
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    font-size:16px;
    font-weight:bold;
}
#docDescription{
    text-align:center;
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    margin-left:5px;
    margin-right:5px;
    height:110px;   
}
#docOpen{   
    text-align:center;      
    margin-left:17.5%;
    margin-right:17.5%;
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
#headerTitle{
    float:left;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:20px;
    text-align:center;
    width:25%;  
}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-size:12px;
    height:80px;    
}
.navOn{
    border-top:3px solid #4C66A4;   
    height:47px;
    padding-top:27px;
}
li {
    float: left;
    width:12%;
    height:50px;
    padding-top:30px;
    text-align:center;
}
a:visited {
    text-decoration: none; 
    color:#000; 
}
li a, .dropbtn {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #000;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
}
li.dropdown {
    display: inline-block;
}
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}
.dropdown-content a:hover {
    background-color: #f1f1f1
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
.btnOpen{
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;
    height:30px;
    width:100%;
    border-radius:5px;
    background-color:#4C66A4;
    color:#FFF;
    font-size:15px;
    font-weight:bold;
}   
.headerTitle{
    font-size:20px;
    text-align:center;  
    vertical-align:middle;
    font-weight:bold;
}
.tbSearch{
    border: 1px solid #848484; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 30px; 
    -moz-border-radius: 30px; 
    border-radius: 30px; 
    outline:0;  
    padding-left:10px; 
    padding-right:10px; 
    margin-top:0;
    margin-bottom:0;
    margin-left:12.5%;
    margin-right:12.5%;
    width:75%;
    height:25px;
    font-size:15px;
}
}

/* Tablet Layout: 481px to 768px. Inherits styles from: Mobile Layout. */

@media only screen and (min-width: 481px) {
}

/* Desktop Layout: 769px to a max of 1232px.  Inherits styles from: Mobile Layout and Tablet Layout. */

@media only screen and (min-width: 769px) {
}
```

**EDIT**

Example to the comment supplied to Sagar Kodte:

[image]

Comment: did you  bootstrap frame work?

Comment: Check answer, i think thats what you wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope it helps you. **EDITED**

```css
@charset "utf-8";
body{
    background:#E8E8E8; 
    overflow-x:hidden;
}
#header{
    width:100%;
    height:80px;
    font-weight:bold;
}
#search{
    height:115px;
    background-color:#4C66A4;   
    color:#FFF;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:18px;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding-top:10px;
}
#navTop{
    height:5px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    background-color:#4C66A4;
}
#documents{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;    
}
#docGrid{
    height:225px;
    margin-left:10%;
    margin-right:10%;
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
}
#docLeft{
    float:left;
    height:222px;
    width:45%;
    background-color:#FFF;
    border-bottom:3px solid #BEBEBE;    
}
#docRight{
    float:right;
    height:222px;
    width:45%;
    background-color:#FFF;
    border-bottom:3px solid #BEBEBE;
}
#docName{
    text-align:center;
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    font-size:16px;
    font-weight:bold;
}
#docDescription{
    text-align:center;
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    margin-left:5px;
    margin-right:5px;
    height:110px;   
}
#docOpen{   
    text-align:center;      
    margin-left:17.5%;
    margin-right:17.5%;
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
#headerTitle{
    float:left;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:20px;
    text-align:center;
    width:25%;  
}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-size:11px;
    height:80px;    
}
.navOn{
    border-top:3px solid #4C66A4;   
    height:47px;
    padding-top:27px;
}
li {
    float: left;
    width:16%;
    height:50px;
    padding-top:30px;
    text-align:center;
}
a:visited {
    text-decoration: none; 
    color:#000; 
}
li a, .dropbtn {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #000;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
}
li.dropdown {
    display: inline-block;
}
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}
.dropdown-content a:hover {
    background-color: #f1f1f1
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
.btnOpen{
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;
    height:30px;
    width:100%;
    border-radius:5px;
    background-color:#4C66A4;
    color:#FFF;
    font-size:15px;
    font-weight:bold;
}   
.headerTitle{
    font-size:20px;
    text-align:center;  
    vertical-align:middle;
    font-weight:bold;
}
.tbSearch{
    border: 1px solid #848484; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 30px; 
    -moz-border-radius: 30px; 
    border-radius: 30px; 
    outline:0;  
    padding-left:10px; 
    padding-right:10px; 
    margin-top:0;
    margin-bottom:0;
    margin-left:12.5%;
    margin-right:12.5%;
    width:75%;
    height:25px;
    font-size:15px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px)  {
    li a { font-size:8px;}
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 320px)  {
    li a { font-size:5px; !important}
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
        <div id="headerTitle">
            <p>Project Archive</p>
        </div>
        <div id="nav">
            <ul>
                <li class="navOn"><a class="active" href="Home.php">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="Home.php">All</a></li>
                <li><a href="Home.php">Categories</a></li>
                <li><a href="Home.php">Quote</a></li>
                <li><a href="Home.php">Support</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropbtn">Settings</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-content">
                    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div id="search">
        <p>Search Your Documents...</p>
        <form action="Home.php" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="search" class="tbSearch">
        </form>
    </div>

    <div id="documents">
        <div id="docGrid">
            <div id="docLeft">
                <div id="docName">
                    <p>Doc Name</p>
                </div>
                <div id="docDescription">
                    <p>This is the area where the description of the document will be displayed.</p>
                </div>
                <div id="docOpen">
                    <table class="btnOpen">
                        <tr>
                            <td>OPEN</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="docRight">
                <div id="docName">
                    <p>Doc Name</p>
                </div>
                <div id="docDescription">
                    <p>This is the area where the description of the document will be displayed.</p>
                </div>
                <div id="docOpen">
                    <table class="btnOpen">
                        <tr>
                            <td>OPEN</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="docGrid">
            <div id="docLeft">
                <div id="docName">
                    <p>Doc Name</p>
                </div>
                <div id="docDescription">
                    <p>This is the area where the description of the document will be displayed.</p>
                </div>
                <div id="docOpen">
                    <table class="btnOpen">
                        <tr>
                            <td>OPEN</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="docRight">
                <div id="docName">
                    <p>Doc Name</p>
                </div>
                <div id="docDescription">
                    <p>This is the area where the description of the document will be displayed.</p>
                </div>
                <div id="docOpen">
                    <table class="btnOpen">
                        <tr>
                            <td>OPEN</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="docGrid">
            <div id="docLeft">
                <div id="docName">
                    <p>Doc Name</p>
                </div>
                <div id="docDescription">
                    <p>This is the area where the description of the document will be displayed.</p>
                </div>
                <div id="docOpen">
                    <table class="btnOpen">
                        <tr>
                            <td>OPEN</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="docRight">
                <div id="docName">
                    <p>Doc Name</p>
                </div>
                <div id="docDescription">
                    <p>This is the area where the description of the document will be displayed.</p>
                </div>
                <div id="docOpen">
                    <table class="btnOpen">
                        <tr>
                            <td>OPEN</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

        <div id="docGrid">
            <div id="docLeft">
                <div id="docName">
                    <p>Doc Name</p>
                </div>
                <div id="docDescription">
                    <p>This is the area where the description of the document will be displayed.</p>
                </div>
                <div id="docOpen">
                    <table class="btnOpen">
                        <tr>
                            <td>OPEN</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="docRight">
                <div id="docName">
                    <p>Doc Name</p>
                </div>
                <div id="docDescription">
                    <p>This is the area where the description of the document will be displayed.</p>
                </div>
                <div id="docOpen">
                    <table class="btnOpen">
                        <tr>
                            <td>OPEN</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Hi there, thanks for answering. Your option has been the most successful so far, but it seems to be having a large space on the right side is there a way to remove this and still have the same results.

Comment: you want to remove that large space on desktop mode or mobile mode?

Comment: Preferably on both if possible if not then just the mobile mode. Thanks again for helping me here.

Comment: Thanks for your help, you have successfully done exactly what I was looking for thanks again for you help

Comment: I just realised that when I tested this code on my mobile device that when the drop down menu is created it is under the settings tab but then has a load of unrequired space to the right so it looks as if the drop down is too wide and creates a scrolling option on the x axis, and therefore the rest of the page is to the left of the drop down when the scroll option is available.  Any ideas on why this might be I've also put an new edit up with an example of this?

Comment: can you please give me link because here on snippet i can't see in mobile version properly

Answer (score 1):

Try using flexbox. I also added 0px margin to html and body element. If you feel better without it, feel free to delete

```css
@charset "utf-8";
html, body{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
body{
    background:#E8E8E8; 
 overflow-x: hidden;
}
#header{
    width:100%;
    height:80px;
    font-weight:bold;
}
#search{
    height:115px;
    background-color:#4C66A4;   
    color:#FFF;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:18px;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding-top:10px;
}
#navTop{
    height:5px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    background-color:#4C66A4;
}
#documents{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;    
}
#docGrid{
    height:225px;
    margin-left:10%;
    margin-right:10%;
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
}
#docLeft{
    float:left;
    height:222px;
    width:45%;
    background-color:#FFF;
    border-bottom:3px solid #BEBEBE;    
}
#docRight{
    float:right;
    height:222px;
    width:45%;
    background-color:#FFF;
    border-bottom:3px solid #BEBEBE;
}
#docName{
    text-align:center;
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    font-size:16px;
    font-weight:bold;
}
#docDescription{
    text-align:center;
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    margin-left:5px;
    margin-right:5px;
    height:110px;   
}
#docOpen{   
    text-align:center;      
    margin-left:17.5%;
    margin-right:17.5%;
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
#headerTitle{
    float:left;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:20px;
    text-align:center;
    width:25%;  
}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-size:12px;
    height:80px;    
 display: flex;
}
.navOn{
    border-top:3px solid #4C66A4;   
    height:47px;
    padding-top:27px;
}
li {
    height:50px;
    padding-top:30px;
    text-align:center;
 display: block;
 flex: 1;
}
a:visited {
    text-decoration: none; 
    color:#000; 
}
li a, .dropbtn {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #000;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
}
li.dropdown {
    display: inline-block;
}
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}
.dropdown-content a:hover {
    background-color: #f1f1f1
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
.btnOpen{
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;
    height:30px;
    width:100%;
    border-radius:5px;
    background-color:#4C66A4;
    color:#FFF;
    font-size:15px;
    font-weight:bold;
}   
.headerTitle{
    font-size:20px;
    text-align:center;  
    vertical-align:middle;
    font-weight:bold;
}
.tbSearch{
    border: 1px solid #848484; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 30px; 
    -moz-border-radius: 30px; 
    border-radius: 30px; 
    outline:0;  
    padding-left:10px; 
    padding-right:10px; 
    margin-top:0;
    margin-bottom:0;
    margin-left:12.5%;
    margin-right:12.5%;
    width:75%;
    height:25px;
    font-size:15px;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 769px) {
 #header{
  width: 80%;
  margin-left: 5%;
 }
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <div id="headerTitle">
            <p>Project Archive</p>
        </div>
        <div id="nav">
            <ul>
                <li class="navOn"><a class="active" href="Home.php">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="Home.php">All</a></li>
                <li><a href="Home.php">Categories</a></li>
                <li><a href="Home.php">Quote</a></li>
                <li><a href="Home.php">Support</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropbtn">Settings</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-content">
                    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div id="search">
        <p>Search Your Documents...</p>
        <form action="Home.php" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="search" class="tbSearch">
        </form>
    </div>

    <div id="documents">
        <div id="docGrid">
            <div id="docLeft">
                <div id="docName">
                    <p>Doc Name</p>
                </div>
                <div id="docDescription">
                    <p>This is the area where the description of the document will be displayed.</p>
                </div>
                <div id="docOpen">
                    <table class="btnOpen">
                        <tr>
                            <td>OPEN</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="docRight">
                <div id="docName">
                    <p>Doc Name</p>
                </div>
                <div id="docDescription">
                    <p>This is the area where the description of the document will be displayed.</p>
                </div>
                <div id="docOpen">
                    <table class="btnOpen">
                        <tr>
                            <td>OPEN</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="docGrid">
            <div id="docLeft">
                <div id="docName">
                    <p>Doc Name</p>
                </div>
                <div id="docDescription">
                    <p>This is the area where the description of the document will be displayed.</p>
                </div>
                <div id="docOpen">
                    <table class="btnOpen">
                        <tr>
                            <td>OPEN</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="docRight">
                <div id="docName">
                    <p>Doc Name</p>
                </div>
                <div id="docDescription">
                    <p>This is the area where the description of the document will be displayed.</p>
                </div>
                <div id="docOpen">
                    <table class="btnOpen">
                        <tr>
                            <td>OPEN</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="docGrid">
            <div id="docLeft">
                <div id="docName">
                    <p>Doc Name</p>
                </div>
                <div id="docDescription">
                    <p>This is the area where the description of the document will be displayed.</p>
                </div>
                <div id="docOpen">
                    <table class="btnOpen">
                        <tr>
                            <td>OPEN</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="docRight">
                <div id="docName">
                    <p>Doc Name</p>
                </div>
                <div id="docDescription">
                    <p>This is the area where the description of the document will be displayed.</p>
                </div>
                <div id="docOpen">
                    <table class="btnOpen">
                        <tr>
                            <td>OPEN</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

        <div id="docGrid">
            <div id="docLeft">
                <div id="docName">
                    <p>Doc Name</p>
                </div>
                <div id="docDescription">
                    <p>This is the area where the description of the document will be displayed.</p>
                </div>
                <div id="docOpen">
                    <table class="btnOpen">
                        <tr>
                            <td>OPEN</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="docRight">
                <div id="docName">
                    <p>Doc Name</p>
                </div>
                <div id="docDescription">
                    <p>This is the area where the description of the document will be displayed.</p>
                </div>
                <div id="docOpen">
                    <table class="btnOpen">
                        <tr>
                            <td>OPEN</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Hi there thanks for answering, it looks like it is working to a degree. However you can't actually read the links as they are off the page. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Sorry for late, try to add `right: 0;` to `.dropdown-content` in css

Comment: This has in fact worked, but only for the mobile site the desktop version it's now pressed against the right of the page. Which of course is what we've told it to do with `right:0;` is there a way to solve this so that the desktop version sits nicely under it? Thanks again for the help.

Comment: Sure, my bad. Delete previous addition, and add this code at the end of the css file: 
`@media all and (max-width: 768px) { .dropdown-content {
    right: 0;
} }`

Comment: I also found two more bugs.
1. Avoid using `body { overflow-x: hidden }`. Scroll-bar shows only because overall width of .tbSearch element is equal to: 75% (element width) + 25% (margins) + 20px (paddings) + 2px (borders) = 100% + 22px. I suggest to change margins to `margin-left: calc(12.5% - 11px);`, and `margin-right: calc(12.5% - 11px);`
Secondly, you are using id's where classes should be used. ID can be used only once, and each element may have only one ID, whereas same classes may be given to different elements, and each element may have few classes, like `class="class1 class2"`

Answer (score 0):

Hope it is what you want.

```css
@charset "utf-8";
body{
    background:#E8E8E8; 
    overflow-x:hidden;
}
#header{
    width:100%;
    min-height:80px;
    font-weight:bold;
  overflow:hidden;
}
#search{
    height:115px;
    background-color:#4C66A4;   
    color:#FFF;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:18px;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding-top:10px;
}
#navTop{
    height:5px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    background-color:#4C66A4;
}
#documents{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;    
}
#docGrid{
    height:225px;
    margin-left:10%;
    margin-right:10%;
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
}
#docLeft{
    float:left;
    height:222px;
    width:45%;
    background-color:#FFF;
    border-bottom:3px solid #BEBEBE;    
}
#docRight{
    float:right;
    height:222px;
    width:45%;
    background-color:#FFF;
    border-bottom:3px solid #BEBEBE;
}
#docName{
    text-align:center;
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    font-size:16px;
    font-weight:bold;
}
#docDescription{
    text-align:center;
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    margin-left:5px;
    margin-right:5px;
    height:110px;   
}
#docOpen{   
    text-align:center;      
    margin-left:17.5%;
    margin-right:17.5%;
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
#headerTitle{
    float:left;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:20px;
    text-align:center;
    width:25%;  
}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-size:12px;
    min-height:80px;
}
.navOn{
    border-top:3px solid #4C66A4;   
    height:47px;
    padding-top:27px;
}
li {
   width: 10%;
  padding:30px 10px 0px 10px;
    height:50px;
    padding-top:30px;
    text-align:center;
  float:left;
}
a:visited {
    text-decoration: none; 
    color:#000; 
}
li a, .dropbtn {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #000;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
}
li.dropdown {
    display: inline-block;
}
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}
.dropdown-content a:hover {
    background-color: #f1f1f1
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
.btnOpen{
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;
    height:30px;
    width:100%;
    border-radius:5px;
    background-color:#4C66A4;
    color:#FFF;
    font-size:15px;
    font-weight:bold;
}   
.headerTitle{
    font-size:20px;
    text-align:center;  
    vertical-align:middle;
    font-weight:bold;
}
.tbSearch{
    border: 1px solid #848484; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 30px; 
    -moz-border-radius: 30px; 
    border-radius: 30px; 
    outline:0;  
    padding-left:10px; 
    padding-right:10px; 
    margin-top:0;
    margin-bottom:0;
    margin-left:12.5%;
    margin-right:12.5%;
    width:75%;
    height:25px;
    font-size:15px;
}
}

/* Tablet Layout: 481px to 768px. Inherits styles from: Mobile Layout. */

@media only screen and (min-width: 481px) {
}

/* Desktop Layout: 769px to a max of 1232px.  Inherits styles from: Mobile Layout and Tablet Layout. */

@media only screen and (min-width: 769px) {
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <div id="headerTitle">
            <p>Project Archive</p>
        </div>
        <div id="nav">
            <ul>
                <li class="navOn"><a class="active" href="Home.php">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="Home.php">All</a></li>
                <li><a href="Home.php">Categories</a></li>
                <li><a href="Home.php">Quote</a></li>
                <li><a href="Home.php">Support</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropbtn">Settings</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-content">
                    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div id="search">
        <p>Search Your Documents...</p>
        <form action="Home.php" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="search" class="tbSearch">
        </form>
    </div>

    <div id="documents">
        <div id="docGrid">
            <div id="docLeft">
                <div id="docName">
                    <p>Doc Name</p>
                </div>
                <div id="docDescription">
                    <p>This is the area where the description of the document will be displayed.</p>
                </div>
                <div id="docOpen">
                    <table class="btnOpen">
                        <tr>
                            <td>OPEN</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="docRight">
                <div id="docName">
                    <p>Doc Name</p>
                </div>
                <div id="docDescription">
                    <p>This is the area where the description of the document will be displayed.</p>
                </div>
                <div id="docOpen">
                    <table class="btnOpen">
                        <tr>
                            <td>OPEN</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="docGrid">
            <div id="docLeft">
                <div id="docName">
                    <p>Doc Name</p>
                </div>
                <div id="docDescription">
                    <p>This is the area where the description of the document will be displayed.</p>
                </div>
                <div id="docOpen">
                    <table class="btnOpen">
                        <tr>
                            <td>OPEN</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="docRight">
                <div id="docName">
                    <p>Doc Name</p>
                </div>
                <div id="docDescription">
                    <p>This is the area where the description of the document will be displayed.</p>
                </div>
                <div id="docOpen">
                    <table class="btnOpen">
                        <tr>
                            <td>OPEN</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="docGrid">
            <div id="docLeft">
                <div id="docName">
                    <p>Doc Name</p>
                </div>
                <div id="docDescription">
                    <p>This is the area where the description of the document will be displayed.</p>
                </div>
                <div id="docOpen">
                    <table class="btnOpen">
                        <tr>
                            <td>OPEN</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="docRight">
                <div id="docName">
                    <p>Doc Name</p>
                </div>
                <div id="docDescription">
                    <p>This is the area where the description of the document will be displayed.</p>
                </div>
                <div id="docOpen">
                    <table class="btnOpen">
                        <tr>
                            <td>OPEN</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

        <div id="docGrid">
            <div id="docLeft">
                <div id="docName">
                    <p>Doc Name</p>
                </div>
                <div id="docDescription">
                    <p>This is the area where the description of the document will be displayed.</p>
                </div>
                <div id="docOpen">
                    <table class="btnOpen">
                        <tr>
                            <td>OPEN</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="docRight">
                <div id="docName">
                    <p>Doc Name</p>
                </div>
                <div id="docDescription">
                    <p>This is the area where the description of the document will be displayed.</p>
                </div>
                <div id="docOpen">
                    <table class="btnOpen">
                        <tr>
                            <td>OPEN</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for answering, I tried your code in both my project and the Run code snippet and they both produce the same result, the settings tab goes under the home tab when the browser is shrunk. Which isn't quite what I was looking for I was trying to get it to still be in line and have a drop down.